# how to create a xml sitemap for react website

Tags: sitemap

I have created a sitemap for my react website. I check website on SEO site checkup it is not showing any error in sitemap but in google search console it showing sitemap "could not fetch".
How do I create a sitemap for my react website.

Comment: That depends on how you create your URLs. How does your router work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sitemap is saved in the **Public** folder of your react project.

You can use this react library called [react-router-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-sitemap).

It uses your routes list to generate a sitemap within your public folder.